# Saving checkbox/option list status?

Tags: forms, admin-menu

my self-made admin panel works just fine, but it doesn't save values of form inputs.

When I type something into textbox and click "save" it is still there after refreshing, thanks to PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="header" value="<?php echo get_option('header'); ?>" />
```

So the PHP echoes its own value to a input and everything is just fine. But what to do when I have list of 10 radio buttons or just a checkbox?

For now I have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showS" value="true">
```

And after clicking on it and saving - it's still "unclicked".

Any helping had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just an html question, not specific to WordPress. Look into `checked="checked"` (for check boxes) or `selected="selected"` (for selects, radio buttons, etc.) In your case,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showS" value="true" 
    <?php if (get_option('showS')==true) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>>
```

Since this is WordPress, though, I should also be reminding you to use the Settings API where possible. Don't try to sanitize and validate all of the inputs yourself unless you really know what you're doing. Here's a link to a tutorial on the Settings API:

http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/

Comment: To be honest I don't know HOW to use Settings on my wordpress admin pages, the link you gave me is the only one live example of that function but it's for a plug, not admin page and I couldn't force it to work for me. I've been everywhere from Codex to that particular page and never found settings well explained.

Comment: Maybe its time for a simpler tutorial on the process, then? I can't think of any offhand... the chapter on plugin development in *Professional WordPress* was helpful to me. But if I find a simpler tutorial, I'll try to remember to come back and post it. Or - better - work through it as far as you can and ask questions here when you get stuck...

Comment: There are couple great WP functions for shorthand [checked() and selected()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2228) checks, highly recommend over writing it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a HTML centric question, but as it happens WordPress does have some helper functions for dealing with checkboxes, select dropdowns, disabled inputs, etc..

http://sillybean.net/2010/09/wordpress-hidden-gems-checked-selected-and-disabled/

Rarst also pointed this out in his comment.

I always use these now, they look more elegant then the self-written alternative methods.